# How to reset fonts

Tags: 12.04, fonts

is there any way to reset fonts? my recent customization made the desktop ugly, now the fonts are not smooth and some are very small.I used ubuntu tweak tool to reset fonts. but it didn't work as thought.is there a configuration file to edit or delete to reset this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK...I found "**a way**"...I installed [Unsettings](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/unsettings-tool-to-disable-global-menu.html) tool and made all font settings *default*. now it's charming like before. I think this is the only way to do it **easily**.